# How can you add new variants to the Container component in MUI V5, using TS Module Augmentation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js, module-augmentation

I'm attempting to add a new variant to the Container component, directly in the `ThemeOptions`.

The documentation explains that we need to use module augmentation to extend the interface so that the ts compiler knows about the new prop we are adding:

```
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';

import '@mui/material/Container';

// -------------------
// This throws error:
// Duplicate identifier 'ContainerProps'.ts(2300)
// Container.d.ts(53, 13): 'ContainerProps' was also declared here.
// -------------------

declare module '@mui/material/Container' {
  interface ContainerProps {
    variant?: string;
  };
}

const defaultThemeOpts: ThemeOptions = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#1BA4DD',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#094074',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiContainer: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'centered' },
          style: {
            textAlign: 'center',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

export default defaultThemeOpts;
```

MUI V5 documentation isn't very clear on how to tackle this and I'm a bit confused as to why module augmentation is not working here.